# ¿Cómo se hace esta consulta en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, ordenamiento

Tengo los siguiente datos:

```
+-----------+--------+
|   Clave   | Nombre |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ184532 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ168542 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ179357 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ167981 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ176648 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ168995 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
|PEMJ161321 | XXXXXX |
+-----------+--------+
```

Y deseo hacer una consulta que me muestre solo las claves que son diferentes en los primeros 6 caracteres y los ordene, es decir, que muestre el siguiente resultado:

```
+-----------+
|   Clave   |
+-----------+
|PEMJ16     |
+-----------+
|PEMJ17     |
+-----------+
|PEMJ18     |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente puedes usar la función [`LEFT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_left), con un `GROUP BY` y `ORDER BY`:

```
select left(clave, 6) as clave
  from tbl
 group by left(clave, 6)
 order by clave
```

... o puedes sustituir el `GROUP BY` por `DISTINCT`:

```
select distinct left(clave, 6) as clave
  from tbl
 order by clave
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/YZHBH49280)</kbd>

Comment: Gracias me funciono perfecto, ya habia consultado el distinct pero la verdad no entendia bien la sintaxis.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar NOT LIKE, o DISTINCT, como sea aquí esta la documentación:
 **DISTINCT**:
[Documentacion_1](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html)

[Documentacion_2(más simplificado)](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

**NOT LIKE:**
[al final ejercicio NOT LIKE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)